# Accessing child element

Tags: php, xml

I have this `xml` code, and I need to get every value from . I've tried but what I get is only the first value of . I wonder what's wrong with my code.

Here's the `xml` code:

```
<item>
    <g:detailed_images>
        <g:detailed_image>hat.png</g:detailed_image>
        <g:detailed_image>tie.png</g:detailed_image>
        <g:detailed_image>eye_glass.png</g:detailed_image>
        <g:detailed_image>watch.png</g:detailed_image>
    </g:detailed_images>
</item>
<item>
    <g:detailed_images>
        <g:detailed_image>shoe.png</g:detailed_image>
        <g:detailed_image>socks.png</g:detailed_image>
        <g:detailed_image>hand_gloves.png</g:detailed_image>
        <g:detailed_image>scarf.png</g:detailed_image>
    </g:detailed_images>
</item>
```

And this is my code:

```
foreach($xpath->evaluate('//item') as $item)
    {
        $detailed_images = $xpath->evaluate('g:detailed_images', $item);

        foreach ($detailed_images as $img)
        {
            $simg = $xpath->evaluate('string(g:detailed_image)', $img);
            echo 'image = ';
            echo $simg;
        }
    }
```

My result is:

```
image = hat.png
image = shoe.png
```

While what I want is this:

```
image = hat.png
image = tie.png
image = eye_glass.png
image = watch.png
image = shoe.png
image = socks.png
image = hand_gloves.png
image = scarf.png
```

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see, you're only getting the first `detailed_image` of each `detailed_images`. So, keeping the way you're doing it, you'd need to have another `foreach` on `$simg` and print each resulting node. But you don't need to do all that XPath querying to get those elements. You can get there just fine with only one query:

```
//item/g:detailed_images/g:detailed_image
```

PHP Code:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadXML($xml);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
foreach($xpath->evaluate('//item/g:detailed_images/g:detailed_image') as $item) {
        var_dump($item->nodeValue);
}
```

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/ocT4R)